# Is there a good way to store things in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In other games I've had to resort to creating storage characters for the purposes stashing items I might find useful in the future, especially when trying to collect sets.

Since Kingdoms is going to have me gathering gems, reagents, items, sets, etc, is there any place I can safely stash what I'm not using?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48770/what-item-classes-dont-take-up-inventory-space to boot.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yep, related, but I'm thinking more along the lines of houses, chests, mules ... whatever have you :)

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50206/10260 ... carrying capacity expansion helps too

Comment: All crafting components don't count to your item limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually you can acquire a house, which when upgraded will have a chest which can store up to 155 items. Apparently over the course of the game you can acquire many such houses, but the first you're likely to find is in Canneroc.

Given that your gems, reagents, and "ingredient" type components stack so nicely in your inventory under their sub-containers, you're unlikely to want to actually stash those. But it's a great place to stash pieces of equipment and all the books you've stolen but not gotten around to reading!

Comment: Are the chests in the different houses independent?  If I have 2 houses can I store 310 items?

Comment: @Stephen I have read that the chest is shared between all your houses (so, a fixed item limit, but you put it in one house but access from another) but I haven't gotten far enough to experience it firsthand.

Comment: The manual (yeah, I read the manual.  Wanna fight about it?!) says that "stash boxes are linked, meaning that your character can access his or her items from any of his or her houses."