# What houses are available in Kingdoms of Amalur?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

As per [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50104/336), the only way to store items in Amalur is via your character's Stash - and the easiest way to access that is from houses you own.

My question is simple: How many houses can I own in KoA? Where are they located? And finally, how do I earn them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of houses are as follows not inlcuding a potential one in alabastra (since I have just arrived)

Canneroc,
Adessa,
Motus Mining,
Rathir,
House of Valor,
Seawatch,

All of the stashes are 100% connected.  You do not get separate stashes thus the 155 item limit carries to each house.  Canneroc is actually the easiest house to fast travel too.  Rathir, Adessa, House of Valor, and Motus mining all offer gold opportunities.  Canneroc regularly receives shipments of a product that can be sold.  Seawatch has the most valuable items form chests, etc,... and is probably the toughest given you have to recruit members to complete it.

edit:

SeaWatch also provides an alch trainer if you complete the necessary task.

Answer (score 8):

1. Gossamer End  - Canneroc
2. Aron Excavations Office - Motus Mining Outpost
3. Sandstone Villa - Adessa
4. Champion's Manor - House of Valor in Alsurend of Detyre
5. Archsage Quarters - Rathir, accessible through the Main Hall of Scholia Arcana
6. Seawatch Castle - Northern part of the Southern section of the Caeled Coast in Klurikon
7. Orbocant - obtained from beating the game
8. Gravehal Keep - from the Dead Kel DLC

Source, including links to information on how to obtain each house: http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Player_Home

Video guides to lots of KOA:TR stuff, including how to get each house: http://www.youtube.com/user/achmetha

Answer (score 3):

I haven't encountered a lot of information about additional houses beyond the first one you get in Canneroc (Gossamer's End) which you can expand at the blacksmith and stay local to all the town services.

Your question seems to be more focused on the stash that the house gives you and it turns out that they're not necessarily connectect.

So far my list of points where you can access your stash from is

- Canneroc: Must complete "A Tangled Web" quest
- Adessa, the Walls: Will trigger when you arrive at the southern Apotyre destination
- Motus Mining Outpost: Not sure, have only read about this one
- Rathir: Rumoured at this point, I haven't good evidence of it

Comment: You get a house in Rathir (well, an underground lair, really) if you complete the mage quest line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get Seawatch castle in Caeled Coast.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also be given a house in the House of Valor arena area after you have competed the House of Valor quest line.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Canneroc house south of Arden's Hut, which you discover in the first main quest.

Once you save a man from spiders, he will ask you to look for a missing search party lead by the city mayor, and kill the mayor.

If you kill the mayor, who can be pretty tough, you will have to complete a harder quest to unlock the house. However, **if you spare the mayor, you can immediately meet him at Canneroc to acquire the house.**

Answer (score 0):

For the Rathir house, it is actually the Archsage Quarters. Once you complete the Scholia Arcania (SP) faction quests, you will receive the key to the Archsage Quarters in the main hall downstairs, of the Scholia Arcania (SP). There, you get your stash, and alchemy, sagecraft and blacksmith tables. In addition, there are treasures all around the quarters. You also get these crazy little bloodthirsty pets that you can feed live chickens to.