# How can I increase my carrying capacity?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In Kingdoms of Amalur, your character starts out with 70 slots of inventory. It sounds like a lot, but when every other dead brownie or kobold earns you a new pair of pants, it's only a matter of time before you're knee-deep in knickers and pantaloons.

I've found one item for sale, a "Backpack" that increases my inventory by 10 slots, but I'm wondering if there are any other ways (or more backpacks!) that can do this.

I want to [loot ALL THE THINGS!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuHVZ.jpg) How else can I increase my inventory in Kingdoms of Amalur? Is there a limit to the maximum number of backpacks I can acquire?!

Comment: As far as I know, backpacks are the only way to increase inventory space, and are scattered for sale around the world. There is probably a finite number of backpack upgrades you can buy.

Comment: Don't [we all](http://penny-arcade.smugmug.com/photos/i-PPTPkRk/0/L/i-PPTPkRk-XL.jpg) want that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you noted, you can buy a backpack to add 10 storage to your inventory.

Backpacks are available from merchants in several of the major towns.  Sterno and other users confirm that they do stack. Purchasing one from Gorhart takes you to 80 and buying the one in Ysa bring you to 90, and so on.

The following vendors sell backpacks:

- Rikka Egest (at The Corner Shop in Gorhart)
- Riona Helt (at Asker's Alley in Ysa)
- Wil Donall (at Main Hall of Scholia Arcana in Rathir)
- Senecer Macit (at Domus Politica in Adessa)
- Illyn Doldran (in Mel Senshir)
- Ampelio (at Idylla Market in Idylla, in the Teeth of Narros DLC)

Since backpacks don't show as inventory items, you can't use them to increase your stash, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, I've bought 1 backpack (from Gorhart) and it doesn't show up as an actual item in your inventory.

Comment: Has anyone found out if you can buy multiples yet?

Comment: @spugsley You can buy multiples and they stack. I just got my 2nd backpack in Ysa and am up to 90 carrying capacity.

Comment: I'm at 110 capacity (and it's still not enough) currently. Forget how many I've bought.

Comment: @Stephen It's possible that this answer doesn't hold true for Casual. [Chibok says](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61750/where-can-i-buy-backpacks-in-koa-in-casual-mode#comment91213_61750) he can't find the backpacks at these locations on casual. Any idea what differences, if any, there are between difficulty modes?

Comment: @Sterno No idea.  I've never played in casual.

Answer (score 1):

I've run around picking 3 up so far and im up in 100 slots so yeah it stacks :)

Comment: Can you recall where you purchased them from? Right now, your answer doesn't do a very effective job at answering the question. The more detail you can add, the *better*. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a hex editor to edit your save. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/tut-how-to-mod-kingdoms-of-amalur-inventory-capacity.681463/).

**Edit:**
Sorry, I didn't quote anything in my previous post but thank you for politely pointing that out :)  I didn't quote anything because 1) I wasn't sure I could even post without an account and 2) the quote would have been quite lengthy. I'm not great with the whole "coding my posts" to make cool links, but I appreciate you taking them time to do that for me.

I hex edited my save today (I'm on PC by the way) and I currently have a max inventory of over 10 million. I'll try to come back and provide a screenshot for proof, but it's already past my bedtime :P The link I provided doesn't seem to be getting around much on the internet so I thought I'd share it here. I also realize I'm a bit late to the party (two months after the last post in here), but this is by far the best solution out there; if you don't consider hex edits cheating.

I hope my comment was useful for you guys. I figured my brief statement and the link were a clear and concise way of relaying the info. Please think of the content over the format before down voting my post into oblivion. I only posted it here to get the info out to you guys.

Happy gaming two legs!

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hello, Renots, and welcome to gaming! I'm here to assure you that you're not being downvoted into oblivion! The issue here is one of, "what happens if the link goes dead?" Then your answer is entirely useless - a broken link, which is not very helpful. By moving the tutorial into your answer (even if it *is* long), you're helping preserve the answer on more of the internet, meaning it's more likely someone will be able to find it when they're looking for it. Lastly, please check the [FAQ] if you haven't already, hopefully it can if you have further questions.

Comment: The tutorial still works, but some instructions: Backup the save file. Open your save file in a hex editor, find the string "inventory_limit", then find the hex values "XX 00 00 00", where XX is the hex value for your current size. 70d is 46h (so if your in-game limit is 70, look for 46 in the editor), 80d is 50h, 90d is 5Ah, 100d is 64h, 110d is 6Eh, 120d is 78h (which I think is the default cap). Convert your desired cap in decimal to hex. 500,000d is 00 07 A1 20 in hex. Reverse the byte order, so 20 A1 07 00. Type it, starting with the byte that originally had 46 or whatever. Save the file.

Comment: If you're on XBox, you have to get the file to your PC to hex edit it. From there, it's the same except you use 00 00 00 46 instead of 46 00 00 00. Then you replace it with the normal byte order. In the above case, you'd use 00 07 A1 20. The maximum I was able to get was 2,130,706,432 slots with FF FF FF 7E (PC) which would be 7E FF FF FF (XBox). Of note, once I edited the file, the number changed places a bit, but I was still able to search for FF FF FF 7E to find it again, and setting it to 50 00 00 00 returned me to the 80 slots I had before screwing around.