# Where can I buy backpacks in KoA in casual mode?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase my carrying capacity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50206/how-can-i-increase-my-carrying-capacity)

I play KoA in casual mode and I want to carry more items in my backpack but I'm unable to find more backpacks. I've already some additional containers in my inventory like for alchemy ingredients, gems and tools but I want more place for weapons and armor. Where can I buy more backpacks? I don't want to cheat and use a hex editor.

Comment: [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50242/8350) from the duplicate question provides an answer.

Comment: The duplicate also specifically asks where one can buy backpacks, despite the more-general title.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: No, it's not. If you read my questions it's more detailed and it's about casual players!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidHoang Then you should ask for more details on the original question.

Comment: Why would casual mode change this?

Comment: There is no difference between Casual mode and any other mode in terms of where the backpack locations are.

Comment: @Sterno: I've looked all over the place and I cannot find any backpack to buy. I'm pretty sure in casual mode you cannot buy additional backpacks.

Comment: @Chibox I'm surprised by that, but I'll take your word for it! If they're not there on casual, the best way to handle this is to leave a comment on the other question indicating that the current answer doesn't cover enough detail. I've already done that for you [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50206/how-can-i-increase-my-carrying-capacity#comment91215_50242) and hopefully the answer will be updated with more info.